# How to align suffixIcon to top of multi line TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

code:

```
TextField(
  maxLines:null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.delete),
  ),
)
```

Everytime a new line is inserted, the icon centers itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a work-around. Just use `suffix` property of `TextField` instead of `suffixIcon`

code:

```
TextField(
  maxLines:null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  suffix: Icon(Icons.delete),
  ),
)
```

output:

[image]

Note: This solution may affect the design of your `TextField` and the `Icon` is not visible when `TextField` is not focused or when it has no data

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I achieved using `Padding` around `Icon`:

[image]

```
Container(
    height: 100,
    child: TextField(
      expands: true,
      maxLines: null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 100),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      )),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: This solution works only if the height of the TextField is fixed. If the height is increased, the alignment gets changed. I want the TextFields height to be dynamic and also maintain alignment.

Comment: Ok I wasn't aware because you didn't mention that in your question @FiroshVasudevan

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done the widget like this way. You may try it.
It will work in TextFormFiled & TextField.

```
      Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey.shade200,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
              // controller: ,
              maxLines: 4,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "Bio",
                  prefixIcon: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  widthFactor: 1.0,
                  heightFactor: 5.0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top:10),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.edit_document,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
               ),
            ),
          ),
```

HappyCoding..